# fullcalendar showing cannot read property hastime

Tags: javascript, node.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to use fullcalendar in node.js, where the parameters for start and end time are pulled from a string with JSON.parse

I've already tried manually entering an array of objects (representing events with starting and ending times) into the events function and it works fine.

This is my current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-74664112-6"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-74664112-6');
    </script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h4 style="text-align:center;margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Heading</h4>

<div id="calendar">

</div>
<div id="availabilities">
    [{"ifvID":1,"title":"testtitle","start_event":"2019-06-22T20:00:00","end_event":"2019-06-22T22:00:00"}]
</div>

<script>
   
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById("availabilities").innerHTML);
        console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById("availabilities").innerHTML));
        console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById("availabilities").innerHTML)[0]);
     var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      editable:true,
      header:{
       left:'prev,next today',
       center:'title',
       right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      events: JSON.parse(document.getElementById("availabilities").innerHTML),
      selectable:true,
      selectHelper:true,
      select: function(start, end, allDay)
      {
       var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
       if(title)
       {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        $.ajax({
         url:"insert.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{title:title, start:start, end:end},
         success:function()
         {
          calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
          alert("Added Successfully");
         }
        })
       }
      },
      editable:true,
      eventResize:function(event)
      {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var title = event.title;
       var id = event.id;
       $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
        success:function(){
         calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
         alert('Event Update');
        }
       })
      },
  
      eventDrop:function(event)
      {
       var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var title = event.title;
       var id = event.id;
       $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
        success:function()
        {
         calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
         alert("Event Updated");
        }
       });
      },
  
      eventClick:function(event)
      {
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
       {
        var id = event.id;
        $.ajax({
         url:"delete.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{id:id},
         success:function()
         {
          calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
          alert("Event Removed");
         }
        })
       }
      },
  
     });
    });
     
</script>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

If run correctly, the event should be showing on the fullcalendar without any errors - however, when I run the code an error message saying "Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined" occurs. Here is the exact error:

```html
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
    at P (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:18300)
    at O (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:18107)
    at V (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:18082)
    at z (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:17993)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:15518
    at Function.map (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:3309)
    at p (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:15486)
    at Array.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:20605)
    at Function.each (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:2715)
    at constructor.Ut (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:20507) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
    at P (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at O (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at V (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at z (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at fullcalendar.min.js:6
    at Function.map (jquery.min.js:2)
    at p (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at Array.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at constructor.Ut (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
```

Comment: Look more carefully at the names of the properties which fullCalendar recognises for events: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object ...and then compare them with the ones you've used. You can't make up the event properties, you have to use the ones specified.

Comment: BTW why did you write your event data into a HTML element, when you could just put it directly into the javascript??

Comment: Works now - it's complicated but the code I showed is from view page source - it's not my 'actual' code. In my actual code, I'm using ejs and I couldn't figure out a way to use values/variables directly in script tags, so I did the next best thing and used them in html, and then used JS to access the HTML.

Comment: I don't see why you can't put an ejs `<%` tag inside the JavaScript part of your file, and make it output some data - just like any other server-side rendering tool, it's used to generate the final content of your page...whether that content happens to be HTML, JavaScript or CSS doesn't really matter as far I can see

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this **hastime** err shows when your event property's start or end date has no value or null value in it